# Ignoring certain field when querying in Rails and ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I know that I can specify certain fields to query the database with `pluck`.

```
ids = Item.where('due_at < ?', 2.days.from_now).pluck(:id)
```

However I would like to know, whether there is a way to specify certain fields I would like to avoid querying from the db. Some kind of anti-pluck?

```
  posts = Post.where(published: true).do_not_lookup(:enormous_field)
```

Comment: Item.where('due_at < ?', 2.days.from_now).map{|a| a.attributes.except!("email", "id").values}

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Model#attribute_names` should return array of columns/attributes. You can exclude some of them and pass to `pluck` or `select` methods.

Something like this:

```
posts = Post.where(published: true).select(Post.attribute_names - ['enormous_field'])
```

Comment: pluck is much faster than select - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pluck

Comment: Not really, `pluck` uses `select` under the hood, it just returns the results as an Array, while `select` as Records.

Comment: @tompave this guys disagrees. over 90% pluck is faster: http://gavinmiller.io/2013/getting-to-know-pluck-and-select/

Comment: Pluck is at least 3x as fast, but you get an array, not active record objects back.

Comment: `pluck` is faster because it extracts specific columns from the DB, then stops and directly returns them as an Array.

`select`, on the other hand, will execute the _same_ query used by pluck, but will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation`. This relation can then be converted into an array of full fledged records.
The slow part is the conversion to `ActiveRecord::Base`