# Deal with a column name 'hash' in a legacy database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have to access a legacy database from within a Rails 5.2 project. Unfortunately I can not change any table column names and the table contains a column with the name `hash` which doesn't work with ActiveRecord (is will throw an error because of `hash` which is an existing method). I don't need that column but I can neither rename nor delete it either.

Is there a way to tell ActiveRecord to not use the `hash` field of a given table?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring certain field when querying in Rails and ActiveRecord](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832738/ignoring-certain-field-when-querying-in-rails-and-activerecord)

Comment: It's not the same problem because the other question is about optimizing something. This question takes care of something that doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`ignored_columns`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/classes/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods.html#method-i-ignored_columns) method that was added to Ruby on Rails in version 5.0 to ignore columns from the database. Quote from the docs:

> `ignored_columns=(columns)`
>
> Sets the columns names the model should ignore. Ignored columns won't have attribute accessors defined, and won't be referenced in SQL queries.

Just add the following to your model:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  self.ignored_columns = %w(hash)
end
```